# I need to request an interrupt...but which one?

Tags: interrupt, embedded-linux

Debian 2.6.30 on a glomation gesbc-9260

with an atmel arm cored chip at91sam9260 -  [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc6221.pdf)

I want an interrupt on a GPIO pin

i need to use request_irq(interrupt number, *handler, conditions, name, id)

but god only knows what interrupt number i use ... if it were ttys0 i'd be fine...

any help would be a godsend

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which GPIO you want.

The file arch/arm/mach-at91/include/mach/gpio.h lists the #defines for requesting GPIOs as IRQs.